# Finding the sum of arithmetic sequence when given two sums

Tags: arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

How do you calculate this? The sum of $4$ terms of an arithmetic sequence is $42$ and the sum of the $3^{rd}$ and $7^{th}$ term is $46$. How do you find the sum of $20$ terms?

$Sn = n/2 [2a+d(n−1)]$ is the equation for working out the sum of an arithmetic series, but how can i rearrange to find for the first term and common difference. I belive it would be using simulatenous equations.

Comment: You are given $S_4$ and $2a + 8d$. These are two equations in two unknowns. Solve them to find the first term and common difference.

Comment: How do you get 2a+8d?

Comment: The third term is $a + 2d$ and seventh term is $a + 6d$.